# Python Plotly adding px objects to a subplot object

Tags: python, express, plotly, subplot

So I'm trying to combine two plots into one. I've made these plots with the plotly.express library rather than the plotly.graphs_objs.
Now, plotly suggests using:  `fig = make_subplots(rows=3, cols=1)` and then `append_trace` or `add_trace`
However, this doesn't work for express objects since the append trace expects a single. trace. How can I add a express figure to a subplot? Or is this simply not possible. One option I've tried was `fig.data[0]` but this will only add the first line/data entry. Rn my code looks like:

```
double_plot = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, shared_xaxes=True)
    histo_phases = phases_distribution(match_file_, range)
    fig = px.line(match_file,
                  x="Minutes", y=["Communicatie", 'Gemiddelde'], color='OPPONENT')
    fig.update_layout(
        xaxis_title="Minuten",
        yaxis_title="Communicatie per " + str(range) + "minuten",
        legend_title='Tegenstander',
    )
    
    double_plot.append_trace(fig.data, row=1, col=1)
    double_plot.append_trace(histo_phases.data, row=2, col=1)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- your code sample does not include creation of data frames and figures. Have simulated
- it is as simple as adding each traces from figures created with **plotly express** to figure created with `make_subplots()`

```
for t in fig.data:
    double_plot.append_trace(t, row=1, col=1)
for t in histo_phases.data:
    double_plot.append_trace(t, row=2, col=1)
```

#### full code

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = px.data.tips()

double_plot = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, shared_xaxes=True)
# histo_phases = phases_distribution(match_file_, range)
histo_phases = px.histogram(df, x="total_bill")
match_file = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Minutes": np.repeat(range(60), 10),
        "Communicatie": np.random.uniform(1, 3, 600),
        "Gemiddelde": np.random.uniform(3, 5, 600),
        "OPPONENT": np.tile(list("ABCDEF"), 100),
    }
)
fig = px.line(match_file, x="Minutes", y=["Communicatie", "Gemiddelde"], color="OPPONENT")
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis_title="Minuten",
    yaxis_title="Communicatie per " + str(range) + "minuten",
    legend_title="Tegenstander",
)

for t in fig.data:
    double_plot.append_trace(t, row=1, col=1)
for t in histo_phases.data:
    double_plot.append_trace(t, row=2, col=1)

double_plot
```

Comment: Oh wow, that makes total sense. I was confused since I expected a loop would just keep adding figures per trace, but by specifying rows and cols it makes sense that they go into a specific figure... Thanks a lot.